# Mautic plugin install on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mautic

I installed mautic plugin in wordpress with a lightsail instance. That means i'm using mautic locally. But when i'm accessing the base url for mautic, i can't see the mautic results. Any ideas?

Comment: Not a programming question, check Mautic documenatation.

Comment: I followed the mautic documentation. Okay, i will check it again. Sorry for posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Wordpress site to be on a public IP address not on a localhost one. Otherwise Mautic can't track the data.

Comment: hi @mautic, you can use the other SE sites that are available for your questions like `https://wordpress.stackexchange.com`

Comment: It says, it is not exist.